# Side by side figures with side captions

Tags: floats, labels

I want my figures to be side by side with a side caption, and I thought I had succeeded in doing this until I've realised every time I have two figures side by side it will label this, say, Figure 1, and then the next time I use a figure it will jump a number and say Figure 3! The referencing is all messed up too and says Figure 2b when I want Figure 1b etc... Please please help my project is due in 2 days!

```
    \begin{document}
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx,floatrow,sidecap,caption,subcaption}
\begin{figure}[h]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{\caption {Critical points generated by Mathematica \cite{mathematica}\label{ppex}}}
{\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ppex1}
\caption{Saddle point at (0,0)}
\label{ppex1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ppex2}
\caption{Centre at (0.5,3)}
\label{ppex2}
\end{subfigure}}
\end{figure}
    \end{document
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: We really need to see a **compilable** and **minimal** example that shows the problem - I can guess that you are using `graphicx`, `floatrow`, and `subcaption` but it's likely that something else in your set up is causing the issue.  So please post a complete, compilable example that shows the problem, following [this advice](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) as needed.

Comment: If you have `\begin{document}` before `\documentclass` and your only problem is screwy numbering, then you are clearly using a version of LaTeX unavailable to the rest of us and we are, unfortunately, unlikely to be of much assistance. Please read the links and advice Thruston provided and edit your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to page 90 of the `floatrow` manual, `floatrow` is incompatible with `sidecap`, so loading both packages is likely to cause problems.

Moreover, you are mixing up different things, I think as I don't think `floatrow` can sort out what you want when the `subfigure` environment is placed inside a `\floatbox`. I think you need boxes inside the boxes, so to speak.

Why not follow the example on page 70 instead?

[image: floats and subfloats]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,floatrow,caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}% example ~p70 of manual for floatrow
    \thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}
    \fcapside[\FBwidth]
    {%
      \begin{subfloatrow}
        \ffigbox[0.32\textwidth]{\caption{Saddle point at (0,0)}\label{ppex1}
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}{}
        \ffigbox[0.32\textwidth]{\caption{Centre at (0.5,3)}\label{ppex2}
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}{}
      \end{subfloatrow}
    }{\caption {Critical points generated by Mathematica\label{ppex}}}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{tiger}
    \caption{Tiger}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that ***it was necessary to add another `figure` in order to reproduce the problem you asked about***. This is what you want your MWE to do. Otherwise, people will compile, shrug and think 'works for me!'. [If they are especially motivated to help, they may tell you this. But they may just assume you need somebody with a specific system to reproduce the issue and move on.]